# Can you generically convert a row in to json in MySql?

Tags: mysql, json, serialization

I want to switch from DynamoDB to AWS Aurora MySql, but I have a roadblock. I have a trigger on some of my Dynamo tables that will fire a lambda function. I need that same functionality in Aurora, and it is provided by the mysql.lambda_async function. The first param is the lambda ARN and the second is the Json that will be sent to the lambda function.

I would like to be able to serialize the new or updated row without having to know all of the columns. It would be inconvenient to have to update the trigger every time we changed/added/removed a column.

Is there any way to serialize a row in MySql without knowing the schema of the table they were selected from?

If not I guess my next question is whether or not there is a way to iterate through the fields in a row so that i could create the function myself. If so I will just create a new SO question.

Comment: Have you read about [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)?

Comment: @BillKarwin So I could find out what the table schema for a row looked like using I_S.Columns, which is very helpful. I think I have an idea of how to do it based on that. Ill give it a shot and post here if it works. Essentially I would need to create a cursor to iterate throw the columns and use MySql equivalent to Eval to retrieve the values for each column. Thanks for the link

Comment: The equivalent of eval that you can use in a trigger is [PREPARE / EXECUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured out a way to do it, but its useless to me. I guess you cant execute a prepared statement inside of a trigger or function, so it doesnt matter.

Here is my code if anyone ever wanted to try it. You pass in the table and key information, it loops through the columns, retrieves the value of each column using a prepared statement, and generates JSON for each column/value pair. There are probably sexier ways to do this but it is functional.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GenerateJson (primaryKey varchar(50), id varchar(250), tableName varchar(200), INOUT json_result varchar(4000))
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_json varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

 -- declare cursor for all table columns
 DEClARE json_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 Select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Where TABLE_NAME = tableName;

 -- declare NOT FOUND handler
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

 OPEN json_cursor;

Set json_result = Concat('{ Table:', '''',tableName,'''', ',', 'KeyName: ', '''', primaryKey, '''', ', KeyValue: ', '''', id, '''', ', ', ' Item: {') ;

 get_json: LOOP

 FETCH json_cursor INTO v_json;

 IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
 LEAVE get_json;
 END IF; 


SET @sql:=CONCAT('SELECT ',v_json, ' from ',tableName, ' WHERE ',primaryKey, ' = ', CONCAT('''',id,''''), ' Into @propVar;');


PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

SET @newJson = CONCAT(v_json, ': ', '"', @propVar, '"');

 SET json_result = CONCAT(' ',json_result, @newJson, ',');

 END LOOP get_json;

 CLOSE json_cursor;

--trim last comma
SET json_result = CONCAT(LEFT(json_result, CHAR_LENGTH(json_result) -1), '');
SET json_result = CONCAT(json_result, ' }}');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```